# Calculate Interest

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Peeta is saving to buy a new oven for his bakery that will cost \$8000. He has \$6,000 to invest at $5 \frac{1}{2} \%$ compounded semi-annually. How long will he need to wait for until he can afford the new oven?

Comment: I can do that for you! What about you give me $5.1 \%$ of the money that Peeta needs to but the new oven? Don't worry though, you can pay me in half the time peeta needs to wait

Comment: Did you try plugging `6000` and `Ans*(1+0.055/2)` into your calculator and mashing Enter repeatedly? Even if you don't know how to use a logarithm, that's simple enough to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $5.5\%$ to be  the rate of interest per annum

So, after $\frac12$ year, the principal $P$ will become $$P\left(1+\frac12\cdot\frac{5.5}{100}\right)=P\left(1+\frac{11}{400}\right)$$

So, after $n$  $\frac12$ year,  the principal $P$ will become $$P\left(1+\frac{11}{400}\right)^n$$

Need to use Logarithm

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense to me. Where did the 100 come from?

Comment: @nels, What's the meaning of $\%$?

Comment: A number as a decimal. I guess you're saying a ratio out of a 100?

6000 (1+ 0.055/2) ^ 2 x 6

Comment: @ $\%$ means per cent$(100)$